How to install anjali Phonetic keyboard tamil layout in Ubuntu 24.04
Currently iam using tamil Phonetic (m17n) layout, but in my office using windows 11 anjali layout, almost both same but for fews words are different so i deciced to use anjali tamil keyboard layout in ubuntu 24.04 but unable to find that, please any one guide me to install Anjali Phonetic keyboard Layout
Thankyou

Ubuntu 24.04, currently using ta-phonetic (m17n), but i want Anjali Phonetic is available for ubuntu ?
